# Trocar imagem com onclick - HTML e JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

Estou desenvolvendo um código para trocar a imagem quando ela for clicada, isso com varias divs, ids para ser trocada pela mesma imagem.
Até consegui trocar da primeira, mas as restantes não trocam, por conta do ID. Mas não consegui pensar ou encontrar nada semelhante.

```
<img src="images/coração.png" class="checkbox-7" id="changeimg" onclick="changeImg();">                 
                    
<img src="images/coração.png" class="checkbox-7" id="changeimg2" onclick="changeImg();">    
                    
<img src="images/coração.png" class="checkbox-7" id="changeimg3" onclick="changeImg();">    
                    
<img src="images/coração.png" class="checkbox-7" id="changeimg4" onclick="changeImg();">
```

```
function changeImg () {
    document.getElementById("changeimg").src="images/coracao-preenchido.png";
}
```

Comment: Estudo sobre forEach()

Comment: Você quer trocar todas as imagens ao clicar em uma delas, ou trocar apenas a que foi clicada?

Comment: @user140828 trocar somente a imagem que foi clicada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<img src="https://i2.wp.com/static3.mangalivre.com/capas/aP9npfL-OIarDT5hIOek-Q/7794/external_cover.jpg?quality=100" class="checkbox-7" onclick="changeImg(this)">                 
                    
<img src="https://i2.wp.com/static3.mangalivre.com/capas/aP9npfL-OIarDT5hIOek-Q/7794/external_cover.jpg?quality=100" class="checkbox-7"  onclick="changeImg(this)">    
                    
<img src="https://i2.wp.com/static3.mangalivre.com/capas/aP9npfL-OIarDT5hIOek-Q/7794/external_cover.jpg?quality=100" class="checkbox-7"  onclick="changeImg(this)">    
                    
<img src="https://i2.wp.com/static3.mangalivre.com/capas/aP9npfL-OIarDT5hIOek-Q/7794/external_cover.jpg?quality=100" class="checkbox-7" onclick="changeImg(this)">    

<script>
function changeImg (el) {
 el.src='https://i2.wp.com/static3.mangalivre.com/capas/5mv8yie5DOFf_A_P0pmSKQ/10310/external_cover.jpg?quality=100';
 
}
</script>
```

Comment: @Leticia caso não der certo ou queira que mude algo me avise que eu dou uma revisada no codigo que postei

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigada!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

function changeImg (event) {
        id = event.target.id

        document.getElementById(id).src = "images/coraçãoPreenchido.jpg"
    }

Answer (score 0):

```html
<img src="images/coração.jpg" class="checkbox-7" id="changeimg" onclick="changeImg(event)">                 
                    
<img src="images/coração.jpg" class="checkbox-7" id="changeimg2" onclick="changeImg(event)">    
                    
<img src="images/coração.jpg" class="checkbox-7" id="changeimg3" onclick="changeImg(event)">    
                    
<img src="images/coração.jpg" class="checkbox-7" id="changeimg4" onclick="changeImg(event)">

<script>
    function changeImg (event) {
        id = event.target.id
        document.getElementById(id).src = "images/coraçãoPreenchidojpg.jpg"
    }
    
</script>
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigada!!!!!!!